# How can i show locally stored array objects on html page in a list?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Below is the data in my local storage -

key - `education`
value - `[{"title":"saurabh","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"},{"title":"aman","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"},{"title":"jessica","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"},{"title":"rosh","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"}]`

I want to show each

**title , description** line by line on my page

my `test.ts`

```
fetchdata = '';
  ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.fetchdata = localStorage.getItem('education'); 
// what do i do next to show this on `test.html`
  }
```

my `test.html`

```
<ion-header>

    <ion-navbar>
      <button ion-button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <ion-title>Education</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>

  </ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

    <button ion-button item-right>
        <ion-icon name="md-add-circle" (click)="save();"></ion-icon>
      </button>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can't save object in storage, but only string. So to save your object you have to:

```
localStorage.setItem('education', JSON.stringify(data));
```

and to read that as object

```
this.fetchdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('education'));
```

than you can use [NgForOf Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) to iterate over array as:

```
<ul id="elements">
    <li *ngFor="let elem of fetchdata">
        {{elem.title}} {{elem.description}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: perfect thanks, 1 thing, if i click on a name, how can i read its properties in the console, once i cana read it, i will then find a way to delete it

Comment: Bind click to `<li>` like:  `<li *ngFor="let elem of fetchdata" (click)="log(elem)">` where log is funcition inside component `log(elem) { console.log("CLICKED: " + elem); }`

Comment: in console i see `CLICKED: [object Object]`

Comment: that is because your element doesn't have toString() method in prototype, but when you put elem in separate log it will work ;) `log(elem) { console.log("CLICKED"); console.log(elem); }`

Comment: interesting it worked, my element doesnt have toString() method in prototype , what you tried to explain i am not clear on this, can you try to explain in a lehman language

Comment: Briefly elem is isn't instance of your custom class so it inherit toString() method from `Object.prototype` which will print you `[object Object]`. When you placed elem in separete log without concatenation to another string then toSting() isn't called cause you print object not as string.

Comment: thanks i got it basically string+ array cannot be displayed in console together , i have made myself understood like this ;)  , now when i click it i can see it in console, what method shall i use to delete it ? It is not right to ask here if you want i can open another question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997713/how-can-i-delete-object-from-an-array

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `*ngFor` structural Directive to display a array of objects

```
<div *ngFor = "let title of fetchData">
  {{title.title}} -- {{title.description}} -- {{title.tagline}} {{title.date}}
</div>
```

Check out this link for the working example [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[{"title":"saurabh","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"}]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: i have seen that but wndering what is wrong, even `this.fetchdata = localStorage.getItem('education'); 
    console.log(this.fetchdata);` is showing correct result - `[{"title":"saurabh","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"},{"title":"gaurav","description":"dd","tagline":"tt","date":"dd"}]` then why this error is coming

Comment: it was down to you not parsing data which i overlooked