# How can i delete object from an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have listed array objects on html page, when i click on any of them i get its info, let me explain how i am doing this

my `test.ts` file

```
this.fetchdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('education'));
 log(elem) { 
    console.log(elem); 

  }
```

my `test.html`

```
 <ul id="elements">
          <li *ngFor="let elem of fetchdata" (click)="log(elem)">
              {{elem.title}} {{elem.description}}
          </li>
      </ul>
```

when i click i see this in console -
[image]

How can i delete the clicked record from locally stored array in key `education` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of the index

```
*ngFor="let elem of fetchdata; let index = index"

deleteItem(index){
    this.fetchdata.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: i am trying to understand ,  in html i am doing this, is it ok - `<li *ngFor="let elem of fetchdata; let index = index" (click)="log(elem,index)">` and in my ts file `log(elem,index) { 
    console.log(elem); 
    console.log(index);
  }` once i get the index number, i can use it to delete

Comment: this is working fine, but data not getting deleted from array in local storage, only being vanished from page

Comment: You are splicing the data from the array not from the actual source. If you are looking for that you need to provide more details.

Comment: after you deleted the item, you need to persist the data to localStorage again using the localStorage.setItem('education', JSON.stringify(this.fetchdata)); or something

Answer (score 3):

Your log function should be,

```
log(elem :any){
   let objDelete = this.fetchdata.indexOf(elem , 0);
   if (objDelete > -1) {
    this.fetchdata.splice(objDelete, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is almost correct you now have to localStorage.removeItem('education')
And localStorage.setItem('education', JSON.stringfy(this.fetchdata))

Comment: Property 'splice' does not exist on type 'string'

Comment: you need to have fetchdata globally and parse it to list

Comment: also you need to update the localstorage once removed